# check_diag is not working properly it is showing win in only 2 "x"/"o"

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

```
def check_diag(user, board):
    #Top left to bottom right
    if board[0][0] == user and board[1][1] == user and board[2][2] == user:
        return True
    elif board[0][2] == user and board[1][1] == user and board[0][2] == user:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: In the `elif`, the last check should be `board[2][0]`, not `board[0][2]`

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your `elif` statement. You have `board[0][2]` twice. It should be `board[2][0]`.

Try this:

```
def check_diag(user, board): 
    #Top left to bottom right 
    if board[0][0] == user and board[1][1] == user and board[2][2] == user: 
        return True 
    elif board[0][2] == user and board[1][1] == user and board[2][0] == user: 
        return True 
    else: return False
```

Comment: please consider accepting the answer to mark the question as resolved.